# How do I force Python to acknowledge files in a sub-directory WITHOUT manually typing the file path

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that can find and open a user-selected file without any prior knowledge of the file location. However, I cannot find a path-manipulation module or function to facilitate this.

I have looked through the os, sys, and wxPython modules and none of the functions I have found seem to be able to return the full-path of the file with the sub-directories included. They all seem to just append the working directory with the file name.( I understand some are using HOMEPATH, or USERPROFILE, but it ends up being the same.)  And this does not create a real path and so can't be used to open the file.

It is really baffling to me that these functions can locate the file in memory, but will not return the path including sub-directories of the working directory.

What is more frustrating is that I am using the File_ctrl object in wxPython as the input interface for the user, and so I KNOW that when the user selects the file somewhere the interpreter is acknowledging the location of the file, but I cannot find what method I need to be using to get the file's full path.

I also realize I could set up a search for the file using os.listdir and os.walk, but I want to avoid having to make that search if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the path of a file selected through a wxPython FileCtrl, use the FileCtrl's [`GetPath`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.FileCtrl.html#wx.FileCtrl.GetPath) method, or combine the output of the `GetDirectory` and `GetFile` methods of the [`FileCtrlEvent`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.FileCtrlEvent.html#wx-filectrlevent) for the selection.

Comment: Yep I ended up using the GetDirectory and GetFilename methods to do this (bound to a folder changed event). It still doesn't necessarily solve this issue if not using wxPython but it works for me now.